# ArcGIS - Identify which buffers intersect each other

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I have a dataset with buildings. I want to calculate which buildings are within 25 meter distance of each other. Therefore, I calculated for each building a 25 meter buffer around the building. Then it is with the spatial join tool easy to calculate how many buffers intersect. This gives a count of how many buffers are interesected.

However, it only provides how many buffers are intersected and not which buffers are intersected. While I want to know which buffers are intersected. In other words, if buffer A intersects buffer B I not only want to know that the count of intersecting buffers is 2, but also that it intersects buffer B. Also see the added picture:

[image]

Is there a tool or function in ArcGIS (Pro) that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Generate Near Table (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm), it generates a table, which contains the distance from all features in feature class A to all the features in feature class B.  The tool has a parameter to specify a search_radius (of 25 meters in your case).

The tool requires an Advanced licensed.